# Get DLL names from running process, possible?

Tags: c#, dll, process

I'm seeking for a way to get DLL names from a running process, sorry if I'm poorly expressing myself though.

I need to "connect" to this process via it's name or PID and retrieve the DLL names that it's using if that's possible.

Regards.

Comment: Yes, that is possible... please show some source code... what have you tried ? what exactly is not working ?

Comment: Certainly possible with PInvoke, the win32 API is EnumProcessModules(Ex). No idea if possible in stock .NET without PInvoke or third party wrappers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You can use the `Process` class. It has a `Modules` property that lists all the loaded modules.

For example, to list all processes and all modules to the console:

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();

foreach(Process process in processes) {
    Console.WriteLine("PID:  " + process.Id);
    Console.WriteLine("Name: " + process.ProcessName);
    Console.WriteLine("Modules: ");

    foreach(ProcessModule module in process.Modules) {
        Console.WriteLine(module.FileName);
    }
}
```

You can of course check `Process.Id` for the PID you would like etc.

For more information check out the documentation for this class:-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx

*Note: This code might get upset for certain system processes which you will not have access permission to.*

Comment: This code will also get upset if the process executing it is 32bit and 64bit modules are being accessed. `"A 32 bit processes cannot access modules of a 64 bit process.`

Comment: @Sam Yeh. I guess you could write some kind of stub you can dump and execute that returns you the list, hackish though :/

Comment: The second foreach loop is what did the trick for me! So simple, yet it still eluded me. Thanks for sharing, Lloyd! You saved me a bunch of headaches :)